# Java 1.7, mouse clicked, get X-Y, and send info forward

Tags: java, swing, position, mouselistener

I have went through many answers here and tried implementing the solutions but, my code still won't work as intended...   Basically I have a lot of buttons, the size is fixed, so I get the row and column by dividing the relaive X and Y of the buttons. Than I need to send the data to a nother proram. It works with the buttons, but not with the mouse click. I'll give you my code and a dummy main, so you can try it out. Both ways to get the mouse listener working are still there. The first is commented out like /*  */ and //
The forwarding code was also removed, to keep this to a working minumum.
Thank you for your time.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DoorMatrix extends JPanel {

    static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private static JButton[][] buttons;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public DoorMatrix(int row, int col) {
        super(new GridLayout(row, col));
        buttons = new JButton[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                final int curRow = i;
                final int curCol = j;
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton((j + 1) + ", " + (i + 1));
                buttons[i][j].addKeyListener(enter);
                buttons[i][j].addMouseListener(new A2());
                // buttons[i][j].addMouseListener(pressedit);
                // addMouseListener(pressedit);
                buttons[i][j].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                            if (curRow > 0)
                                buttons[curRow - 1][curCol].requestFocus();
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                            if (curRow < buttons.length - 1)
                                buttons[curRow + 1][curCol].requestFocus();
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                            if (curCol > 0) {
                                if (curCol != 5) {
                                    buttons[curRow][curCol - 1].requestFocus();
                                } else
                                    buttons[curRow][curCol - 2].requestFocus();
                            }
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                            if (curCol < buttons[curRow].length - 1) {
                                if (curCol != 3) {
                                    buttons[curRow][curCol + 1].requestFocus();
                                } else
                                    buttons[curRow][curCol + 2].requestFocus();
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        } // end of switch
                    }
                });
                add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private KeyListener enter = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                ((JButton) e.getComponent()).doClick();
                y = ((JButton) e.getComponent()).getX();
                x = ((JButton) e.getComponent()).getY();
                if (x != 0) {x = (x / 26);}
                x++;
                if (y != 0) {y = (y / 54);}
                y++;
                System.out.print(y + ". module " + x + ". door \n");
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
            }
            if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {f.dispose();}
        }
    };



    /*
private MouseListener pressedit = new MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
if (m.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
((JButton) m.getSource()).doClick();
y = ((JButton) m.getSource()).getX();
x = ((JButton) m.getSource()).getY();
if(x != 0){x = (x / 26);}
x++;
if(y != 0){y = (y / 54);}
y++;
System.out.print(y + ". module " + x + ". door \n"); x =0; y =0;} }};
         */

    public class A2 extends MouseAdapter {
        public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            ((JButton) e.getSource()).doClick();
            y = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getX();
            x = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getY();
            if (x != 0) {x = (x / 26);}
            x++;
            if (y != 0) {y = (y / 54);}
            y++;
            System.out.print(y + ". module " + x + ". door");
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        } // end of event

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    } // end of adapter

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 7;
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new DoorMatrix(12, 9));
        while (a < 2) {
            while (b < 12) {
                buttons[b][a].setVisible(false);
                b++;
            }
            a++;
            b = 7;
        }
        a = 4;
        b = 0;
        while (b < 12) {
            buttons[b][a].setVisible(false);
            b++;
        }
        b = 7;
        a = 7;
        while (a < 9) {
            while (b < 12) {
                buttons[b][a].setVisible(false);
                b++;
            }
            a++;
            b = 7;
        }
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- Don't use `KeyListener` with buttons, 2- Don't use `ActionListener` with buttons...use a `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `KeyListener`s with buttons
2. Don't use `MouseListener`s with buttons

Buttons are designed to operate with `ActionListener`s or `Action`s.

In your case, I would suggest that the `Action` API provides you with the greatest flexibility, as you can pass the physical row/col position of the button within the array that the button appears and then re-use this information without needing to rely on performing calculations.

This takes care of what happens when the user clicks the button and presses the "action" key (typically the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key)

For example, you could replace your `KeyListener` and `MouseListener` with something like...

```
public class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int row, col;

    protected ButtonAction(int j, int i) {
        putValue(NAME, (j + 1) + ", " + (i + 1));
        row = i;
        col = j;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Look, button @ " + getCol() + "x" + getRow() + " was activated, that was easy...");
    }

}
```

Which will print out the index of the row/col of the button within the `buttons` array when it is actioed.  We can reuse this information later.

We can replace the `KeyListener` with the key bindings API, for example...

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");

ActionMap am = getActionMap();
am.put("up", new MoveAction(0, -1));
am.put("down", new MoveAction(0, 1));
am.put("left", new MoveAction(-1, 0));
am.put("right", new MoveAction(1, 0));
```

Which uses

```
public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int colDelta;
    private int rowDelta;

    public MoveAction(int colDelta, int rowDelta) {
        this.colDelta = colDelta;
        this.rowDelta = rowDelta;
    }

    public int getColDelta() {
        return colDelta;
    }

    public int getRowDelta() {
        return rowDelta;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Component owner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
        if (owner instanceof JButton) {
            JButton btn = (JButton) owner;
            Action action = btn.getAction();
            if (action instanceof ButtonAction) {
                ButtonAction ba = (ButtonAction) action;
                int row = ba.getRow();
                int col = ba.getCol();

                do {
                    row += getRowDelta();
                    col += getColDelta();
                    if (row < 0) {
                        row = buttons.length - 1;
                    } else if (row >= buttons.length) {
                        row = 0;
                    }

                    if (col < 0) {
                        col = buttons[row].length - 1;
                    } else if (col >= buttons[row].length) {
                        col = 0;
                    }
                } while (!buttons[row][col].isVisible());

                buttons[row][col].requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which basically looks up the currently focused component, determines if it's `JButton` or not, if it contains a `ButtonAction` or not and if those conditions are try, it will extract the `row` and `col` position of the `ButtonAction`.  This information is then modified (the deltas are applied) and the next focusable button is looked and focused...

As a fully runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DoorMatrix extends JPanel {

    static JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private static JButton[][] buttons;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public DoorMatrix(int row, int col) {
        super(new GridLayout(row, col));
        buttons = new JButton[row][col];

        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");

        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        am.put("up", new MoveAction(0, -1));
        am.put("down", new MoveAction(0, 1));
        am.put("left", new MoveAction(-1, 0));
        am.put("right", new MoveAction(1, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(new ButtonAction(j, i));
                add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                int a = 0;
                int b = 7;
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new DoorMatrix(12, 9));
                while (a < 2) {
                    while (b < 12) {
                        buttons[b][a].setVisible(false);
                        b++;
                    }
                    a++;
                    b = 7;
                }
                a = 4;
                b = 0;
                while (b < 12) {
                    buttons[b][a].setVisible(false);
                    b++;
                }
                b = 7;
                a = 7;
                while (a < 9) {
                    while (b < 12) {
                        buttons[b][a].setVisible(false);
                        b++;
                    }
                    a++;
                    b = 7;
                }
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setResizable(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {

        private int row, col;

        protected ButtonAction(int j, int i) {
            putValue(NAME, (j + 1) + ", " + (i + 1));
            row = i;
            col = j;
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public int getCol() {
            return col;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Look, button @ " + getCol() + "x" + getRow() + " was activated, that was easy...");
        }

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private int colDelta;
        private int rowDelta;

        public MoveAction(int colDelta, int rowDelta) {
            this.colDelta = colDelta;
            this.rowDelta = rowDelta;
        }

        public int getColDelta() {
            return colDelta;
        }

        public int getRowDelta() {
            return rowDelta;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component owner = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
            if (owner instanceof JButton) {
                JButton btn = (JButton) owner;
                Action action = btn.getAction();
                if (action instanceof ButtonAction) {
                    ButtonAction ba = (ButtonAction) action;
                    int row = ba.getRow();
                    int col = ba.getCol();

                    do {
                        row += getRowDelta();
                        col += getColDelta();
                        if (row < 0) {
                            row = buttons.length - 1;
                        } else if (row >= buttons.length) {
                            row = 0;
                        }

                        if (col < 0) {
                            col = buttons[row].length - 1;
                        } else if (col >= buttons[row].length) {
                            col = 0;
                        }
                    } while (!buttons[row][col].isVisible());

                    buttons[row][col].requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. I'll analyze this code more in dept; to avoid future mistakes. Have a nice day.